# How to add NSLayoutConstraints Programmatically

Tags: ios, nslayoutconstraint, programmatically-created

I want to add a button as subview of root view. Button must be place horizontally at centre as well as vertically at centre of superview. I'm using `NSLayoutConstraints` programatically. This is my code.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var button: UIButton!

    override func motionEnded(motion: UIEventSubtype, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        button = UIButton()
        button.setTitle("Hello World", forState: .Normal)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        button.sizeToFit()
        self.view.addSubview(button)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: .CenterY, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        ])
    }
}
```

I'm getting following warning message, also I didn't get desired results.

> 2016-07-20 11:01:10.187 build[26982:309535] Unable to simultaneously
>   satisfy constraints.  Probably at least one of the constraints in the
>   following list is one you don't want.
>
> Try this:
>
> (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't
>   expect;
>
> (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints
>   and fix it.   (Note: If you're seeing
>   NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer
>   to the documentation for the UIView property
>   translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)  (
>       "",
>       "",
>       "
>   (Names: '|':UIViewControllerWrapperView:0x7faa4be31770 )>",
>       "" )
>
> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
>
> Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints
>   to catch this in the debugger. The methods in the
>   UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in
>    may also be helpful. 2016-07-20 11:01:10.188
>   build[26982:309535] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
>     Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one
>   you don't want.
>
> Try this:   (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which
>   you don't expect;
>
> (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints
>   and fix it.   (Note: If you're seeing
>   NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer
>   to the documentation for the UIView property
>   translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)  (
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "
>   (Names: '|':UIViewControllerWrapperView:0x7faa4be31770 )>" )
>
> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
>
> Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints
>   to catch this in the debugger. The methods in the
>   UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in
>    may also be helpful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`NSLayoutConstraint` is one of the way is used to add autolayout constraints dynamically.

```
let new_view:UIView! = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(20, 20, 100, 100));
new_view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor();
new_view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
view.addSubview(new_view);
NSLayoutConstraint(item: new_view,
        attribute: .Leading,
        relatedBy: .Equal,
        toItem: view,
        attribute: .LeadingMargin,
        multiplier: 1.0,
        constant: 0.0).active = true
NSLayoutConstraint(item: new_view,
        attribute: .Top,
        relatedBy: .Equal,
        toItem: view,
        attribute: .TopMargin,
        multiplier: 1.0,
        constant: 20.0).active = true
NSLayoutConstraint(item: new_view,
        attribute: .Height,
        relatedBy: .Equal,
        toItem: new_view,
        attribute:.Width,
        multiplier: 2.0,
        constant:0.0).active = true
NSLayoutConstraint(item: new_view,
        attribute: .Width,
        relatedBy: .Equal,
        toItem: nil,
        attribute: .NotAnAttribute,
        multiplier: 1.0,
        constant: 100.0).active = true
```

set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `false` and call `layoutifneeded` method.